# linux - issues running java applications / issues launching flashtool

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, android, dependencies

i'm trying to use the unzipped http://www.flashtool.net/downloads.php folder for rooting phones,

but when I `sudo ~/FlashTool/FlashTool &`

the console outputs

```
Error: dl failure on line 604
Error: failed /home/mathias/FlashTool/x10flasher_native/jre/lib/server/libjvm.so, because /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/mathias/FlashTool/x10flasher_native/jre/lib/server/libjvm.so)
```

So I `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jre` (ubuntu 16.04) and replace '11' by '9' in the startup script as in here : https://github.com/Androxyde/Flashtool/issues/121

But then at launch the console outputs :

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: gui/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 53.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:939)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/SecureClassLoader.java:152)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:553)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.access$200(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:88)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$3.run(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:466)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader$3.run(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:460)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-internal/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:459)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:406)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/BuiltinClassLoader.java:364)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoaders.java:184)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@9-internal/ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(java.base@9-internal/LauncherHelper.java:585)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(java.base@9-internal/LauncherHelper.java:497)
```

Here is my java versions :

```
~/FlashTool $ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
[12:00:28] ~/FlashTool $ javac -version
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-5-jdk
 * openjdk-8-jdk-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jdk
 * gcj-4.9-jdk
 * openjdk-9-jdk-headless
```

What should I do to be able to launch flashtool ?

Regards

---

Edit for @mureinik :

I installed java14 :

```
~/FlashTool $ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/jdk-14
```

But still:

```
[05:48:58] ~/Fjava -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

and I upgraded glibc :

```
[05:51:03] ~/FlashTool $ apt-cache policy libc6
libc6:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu11.2
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu11.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu11.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

But still can't launch that software, what should I do please?

Comment: this is for up.

Answer (score 0):

The java program you're using uses class version 58, which means you need java 14 or higher to run it.

Instead of downgrading your java version to match the glibc version you have, you need to install java 14 and **upgrade** glibc so this java version can be used.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've edited the initial post due to the various upgrades but problem persists